# Executing constructor from Parent class to Child class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, reserved-words

In what situations should I execute a constructor of the parent class for a child class? And why use the "base" reserved word?

Exemple:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, do not post code as images

Comment: Code as images are useless because 1) Posts are *supposed* to help many many future visitors with similar problem(s).  Image cant be searched so it makes it difficult for search engine to use them 2) It makes it much harder for those who may want to help - they cant copy and paste your code as a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor of the base class is *always* called. Or more exact, *one* constructor of the base class. If you don't specify which one (by using the `base` reserved word), the default constructor of the base class is called (that means the one with no arguments). If the base class has no constructor without arguments, a compiler error occurs. With the `base` keyword, you specify that you want to call a certain constructor. Here are some simple examples:

```
public class Base 
{
    private int _a;
    public Base() // default ctor
    {_a = 0;}
    public Base(int a) // a ctor with an argument
    {_a = a;}
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived() : base(2) // call the ctor with argument "2"
    {}
    public Derived(bool b) // uses the ctor without argument of the base class (_a will stay 0)
    {
    }
}
```

The keyword `base` here is used as a generic placeholder for the name of the base class. The only other word syntactically allowed there would be `this` (if you want to call a constructor of the *same* class)

Answer (score 0):

If you not use :base word for child constructor.

Default constructor of parent will be executed.

If you have some basic construnctor in base class and you have some fields in it and want to fill it using basic constructor you should use base keyword.